# TextMate grammar - avoid external 'include' overriding local patterns

Tags: syntax-highlighting, atom-editor, textmate, tmlanguage

Tweaking a Atom IDE grammar for SaltStack which has the below pattern but the `source.python` seems to be overriding one or more of the patterns that are defined in the SaltStack grammar file.

```
  {
    'include': 'source.python'
  }
```

How can I set a priority or override to avoid this if there is a conflict in a external grammar include? So that the SaltStack grammar pattern takes precedence.

I tried ordering the local grammars order of patterns to see if putting my desired definition at the top would win but no luck.

Thanks.